# Collect users who posted items with ActsasTaggable on Tag in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using Rails 3 and Acts as taggable on in my application.

I am fetching the articles associated with the tag by

```
Article.tagged_with("tagname")
```

and

```
Blog.tagged_with("tagname")
```

Now i would like to collect  all the users from the above
i.e.., people who are all posted articles and blogs with this tag
Please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your model relationships are designed you may probably access that from

`Blog.tagged_with("tagname").users` for example.

Don't forget you can use `debug`for collecting more information about a specific object.